# MySQL using table field in subquery as condition

Tags: mysql, subquery, conditional-statements, having

After a lot of searching I came to following sql statement:

```
SELECT a.*, b.name as producer ,
    (SELECT ROUND(AVG(average)) 
    FROM `abc123_pb_carexperience` d 
    LEFT JOIN `abc123_pb_cars` e on d.car_id=e.id HAVING name LIKE '%a.name%') as avgrating
FROM abc123_pb_brands a
LEFT JOIN abc123_pb_producer as b on a.producer_id = b.id
ORDER BY a.name ASC
```

The point of interest is the condition HAVING name LIKE in the subquery. It works, if I write there the name as string (HAVING name LIKE '%bmw%'), but I have to use the name field of table a to get all average ratings for the specific brand. Is there any idea how to accomplish that? Thanks.

Comment: Consider providing DDLs (or an SQLFIDDLE) for the above, including a representative data set and desired and corresponding result set, as well as a plain english description of what it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your inner subquery should looks like:

```
  (SELECT ROUND(AVG(average)) 
    FROM `abc123_pb_carexperience` d 
    LEFT JOIN `abc123_pb_cars` e on d.car_id=e.id 
    WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',a.name,'%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query like that

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.name as producer,
  ROUND(AVG(d.average)) as avgrating
FROM abc123_pb_brands a
  LEFT JOIN abc123_pb_producer as b
    on a.producer_id = b.id
  LEFT JOIN `abc123_pb_carexperience` d
    ON d.name LIKE '%a.name%'
  LEFT JOIN `abc123_pb_cars` e
    on d.car_id = e.id
ORDER BY a.name ASC
```